# Named parameters in method signature

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, optional-parameters, named-parameters

In C# - Optional parameters - creates a completion to the other un-supplied parameters.

so if I write:

```
void Go(int a, bool isFalse = true)
```

and call `Go(a)`

it actually emit il code for `Go(a, true)`.

What about named parameters and **how does switching the order thing** works behind the scenes?

for example :

```
  Go(isFalse:true, a:1) //order has been switched.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Go(a)` it calls `Go(a, true)` not `Go(a, false)`. For example;

```
using System;

namespace Programs
{
    public class Program
    {      
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Go(5);
        }

        static void Go(int a, bool isFalse = true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Int is {0}, Boolean is {1}", a, isFalse);
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

> Int is 5, Boolean is True

You are setting `isFalse` value to `true` if it isn't used when its called. But if you care about orders you must use which order do you describe in your method. For example;

If you have a method like

`SomeMethod(bool isFalse, bool isFull, bool isStacked)`

and when you call this method like

`SomeMethod(true, false, true)`

your method works like

`isFalse = true`, `isFull = false` and `isStacked = true`

because of the order. But sometimes when your method has a lot of parameters which you can mix the order, you can use named parameters came with `C# 4.0`. Which based same method, you can it like this;

`SomeMethod(isStacked: true, isFull: false, isFalse = true)`

is equal call to

`SomeMethod(true, false, true)`

Comment: yeah I got confused with the true/false. fixing.

Answer (score 3):

For example, if you have something like this

```
void Go ( int a , bool isFalse, bool isEmpty)
```

After your call `Go(1,isEmpty : true, isFalse : false)` it will generate function call like this

```
Go ( 1, false, true)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Go(a)` will compile to `Go(a, true)`. It has the implication that if the default value of an argument is changed in a referenced library the calling code needs to be recompiled.

As a rule of thumb named (and default) parameters are just a compiler trick. The calling rule at the runtime level is the same as previous versions.

So in consequence calling `Go(isFalse = true, a = 1)` will in fact compile to `Go(1, true)`.

Comment: how does it answer to my question ( and not to the preview I gave ) ?

Comment: i did specify that everything is a compiler trick so it should imply that named parameters follow the same rule. They are repositioned by the compiler at the calling site. I'll edit my response.

Comment: `Go(a)` will compile to `Go(a, true)` not `Go(a, false)`